# Run two scripts one after another with a systemd service

Tags: systemd-service, systemd-timers

I have two scripts, what I would like to do is:

- at 1am, the first one runs
- once the first one stops, **and this is a condition**, the second one fires

So, should i use:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre = script.py
ExecStart = secondscript.py
```

or

```
[Service]
Type = oneshot
ExecStart = first.py
ExecStart = second.py
```

`man` notes this:

> Note that `ExecStartPre=` may not be used to start long-running processes. All processes forked off by processes invoked via `ExecStartPre=` will be killed before the next service process is run.

And my scripts can be long-running ones (some hours each).

Or is there a better way to ensure second runs only after first is fully-executed?

Also, this service is called by a timer:

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 1:00:00
Unit = script.service
```

and i want only **one instance** of this running; even if the `script.service` takes 3 days to run, the next run should be reported to the next day after it finishes, at 1:00:00. Is this the default?